# How to create a table on start up using docker-compose, typeORM and MySql?

Tags: mysql, typescript, docker, docker-compose, typeorm

For an assignment, I'm trying to develop a simple API in containers, using docker compose. As it is right now, everything works well, except that typeORM doesn't auto-generate a table from an entity.

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  DOPS-mysql:
    image: mysql/mysql-server
    environment:
      name: DOPS-mysql
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'DOPSDB'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
    volumes:
      - ./mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - '3360:3360'
  web:
    build: ./server
    depends_on:
      - DOPS-mysql
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'
```

The `Dockerfile` it builds from on the web service

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /server

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN  yarn build

EXPOSE 4000

CMD yarn docker
```

Here's my `CreateConnection` function

```
createConnection({
        type: "mysql",
        host: "DOPS-mysql",
        port: 3360,
        database: "DOPSDB",
        username: "user",
        password: "password",
        logging:false,
        synchronize:true,
        entities:[Food]
    })
```

And my entity :

```
import { Field, Int, ObjectType } from "type-graphql";
import { BaseEntity, Column, CreateDateColumn, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from "typeorm";

@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Food extends BaseEntity {
    @Field(() => Int)
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!:number;

    @Field()
    @Column()
    name:string;

    @Field()
    @Column()
    taste:string;

    @Field()
    @Column()
    type:string;

    @Field()
    @Column({nullable:true})
    objectivity?:boolean;

    @Field()
    @CreateDateColumn()
    createdAt: Date;

    @Field()
    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updatedAt: Date;
}
```

As I understand it, once the database has been created and the connection established, typeORM is supposed to auto-generate the tables according to the entities, but it does not in this instance. What am I missing ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

**EDIT :**
Here's the error message displayed in appolographql sandbox when I try to access the Foods table :

```
message": "No repository for \"Food\" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current \"default\" connection?"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your port mapping (`host_port:container_port`) for MySQL server is not correct. It should be `3306` on the container side. `host_port` (`3360`) can be chosen by you.

And `depends_on` does not control the dependency as you think. It is the container running order. You need to create a network between these two containers to establish the communication.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  DOPS-mysql:    
    ...
    ...
    ports:
      - '3360:3306'
    networks:
      - mynetwork
  web:
    ...
    ...
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=DOPS-mysql

networks:
    mynetwork:
```

And access the env variable (`MYSQL_HOST`) in the web container code like below.

```
createConnection({
        type: "mysql",
        host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST || "localhost",
        port: 3360,
        database: "DOPSDB",
        username: "user",
        password: "password",
        logging:false,
        synchronize:true,
        entities:[ "./entities/*.ts" ]
    })
```

```
@Entity('Food')
export class Food extends BaseEntity {
```

Comment: @Morgade, check this out !!

Comment: Everything seems to work the same way before and after modifying the container-side port.

Comment: When I try doing that, I get the following error upon running docker-compose up : `ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.networks: 'mynetwork'`

Comment: I have removed the quotation marks, can you check now

Comment: Still the exact same error

Comment: last section of networks should be in the same level of services and version not inside the services block. That's the issue

Comment: Now it compiles, but I still get the same error message in the sandbox when I try to access the Foods tables. ```message": "No repository for \"Food\" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current \"default\" connection?"```

Comment: where are the entity files relative to the  file which has `createConnection` defined? There should be a solution for it here => https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3017

Comment: If my index.ts is in . , then my entity is in ./entities/Food.ts

Comment: Try with this => `entities:[ "./entities/*.ts" ]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240679/discussion-between-morgade-and-amila-senadheera).